# What type of scrolling is this? (Dynamic Titles)

Tags: android, scrollview

[Here's a gif of the scrolling.](http://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3724717677.gif)

The gif linked is from on iHeartRadio's Android app. I had two questions, one, does this type of scrolling have a name? I've done quite a bit of searching without any real idea of what to call this which has made finding results a little difficult. That being said,  is there any sort of (Android) library available to implement something similar? Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: AFAIK, they're called sticky headers. Here's a link that I see referenced often: http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/

Comment: Here's a lib you can try https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: The [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/) library has an implementation.